# C# Windows Form Coloring Random Button

Tags: c#, windows, forms

What should I write where I put the question mark below? Each time to change the color of a button.

I can keep the names from the list , but I can not button the background color.

```
buttonList[rndNumber].Name ??? Back.Color = Color.Red;
```

---

```
int satir, sutun, minute, tik;
List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();
Random rnd = new Random();

private void timerRandom_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rndNumber = rnd.Next(0, satir*sutun);

    // buttonList[rndNumber].Name ??? Back.Color = Color.Red;
    //  should change the color of the buttons I created below
}

int i = 0, j = 0;
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel.Controls.Clear();

    switch (comboBoxLevel.Text)
    {
        case "1.Seviye":
            satir = 5; sutun = 5; minute = 60000; tik = 5000;
            break;
        case "2.Seviye":
            satir = 7; sutun = 7; minute = 120000; tik = 5000;
            break;
        case "3.Seviye":
            satir = 9; sutun = 9; minute = 1800000; tik = 500;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < satir; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sutun; j++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = "btn" + i + j;
            // btn.Text = "Button" + i + " , " + j;
            btn.Size = new Size(80, 60);
            btn.Location = new Point(i * 80, j * 60);
            btn.Click += buttonClick;
            panel.Controls.Add(btn);
            buttonList.Add(btn);
        }
    }
    timerRandom.Interval = tik;
    timerRandom.Start();                 
}
```

Comment: Why do you care about the name? You have the control, just assign a background color to it. It's a simple property assign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the original background color:

```
 for (i = 0; i < satir; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sutun; j++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = "btn" + i + j;
           // btn.Text = "Button" + i + " , " + j;
            btn.Size = new Size(80, 60);
            btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
            btn.Location = new Point(i * 80, j * 60);
            btn.Click += buttonClick;
            panel.Controls.Add(btn);
            buttonList.Add(btn);
        }
    }
```

To change the background color AFTER you've created the button, add the following to your buttonClick method:

```
private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        b.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
    }
```

To change the background color of a button you name, use:

```
private void changeColor(string buttonName,System.Drawing.Color newColor)
    {
        Button b = (Button)Controls.Find(buttonName, true)[0];
        b.BackColor = newColor;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to set the [`BackColor` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158232(v=vs.110).aspx) of the button, no need to care about the `Name`:

```
buttonList[rndNumber].BackColor = Color.Red;
```